# Pure IList return

Tags: c#, interface

Today i get a code to use, and i saw this return

```
  public IList p()
  {
      return new ListItemCollection();
  }
```

Where are the type of the list? Until today i only use methods like this:

```
public List<string> method() {}
public IList<string> method() {}
...
```

So what i should do when i try use **p()** method:

```
var list = p();
check typeof(list)?
```

Could someone tell me why use just **IList** instead IList with type?

Comment: I think we are missing some context. Where did you see this code? What is the function trying to do?

Comment: And if you look at the [class on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx), you can see that a `ListItemCollection` impliments a `IList`

Comment: Nuce gunr2171 but the question is why the return is a pure IList without type? ( some guys already answer )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `IList` is a non-generic version of `IList<T>`, much like `Hashtable` is a non-generic version of `Dictionary<T>`.  It so happens that your code uses a non-generic `IList` which means that you need to be careful to check the types of the objects stored in the list because they can be anything.

You can check the type of the item like this:

```
object item = yourList[0];
if(item != null && item.GetType() == typeof(string)) // replace string with another type if you like
{
    // checks that the item at index 0 isn't null and is of type String.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`IList` is a type inherited from .NET 1.x, which did not have generic types. It was more or less replaced with `IList<T>`, and functions basically as an `IList<object>`.